# Functional programming in React Function Components

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, react-functional-component

If I wanted to follow FP principals should my inner functions be pure in this React Function Component?  Or is it fine due to the nature of this component and the fact that it is a Function Component? (because, I'm probably incorrect in my technical description, that it's a type of closure. and therefore it needs to change and access the state.)

```
const Component = ({data, onChange}) => {

  const [list, setList] = useState(data);

  const removeItem = (id) => {
    const newList = list.filter(item => item.id !== id);
    setList(newList);
    ... do something else here onChange ...
  }

  return (
    <>
      {list.map(({text, id}) => (
         <div onClick={() => removeItem(id) }>{text}</div>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}
```

**Update**
Specifically should I be concerned that `removeItem` reference `list` and `setList` which are not inputs to this function when I'm trying to apply functional programming principals.

Comment: Do you have any concrete example of what kind of impurities you're worried about? Is it the `setList` you're thinking of?

Comment: Yeah, `list` and `setList` being referenced inside of that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**About `list`:**

```
const newList = list.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
```

Using the High Order Function `.filter()` we are making a copy of it and keep it as immutable data. So, we created a new list based on the old list and the filter condition maintained the immutability.

**About `setList`:**

```
setList(newList);
```

The workaround to avoid mutation will use the spread operator to spread all key/value pairs from the state object into the new state object (a similar idea as we normally do inside reducers) and it can look like this:

```
setList({ ...list, list: newList });
```

Also, we can use function delegation to encapsulate the method allowing the function to be composed (passed as data)

```
  const isDifferentID = item => item.id !== id;

  const removeItem = (id, setList, list) => setList({...list, list: list.filter(item => isDifferentID(item))});
```

**Finally, all together:**

```js
const Component = ({data, onChange}) => {

  const [list, setList] = useState(data);

  const isDifferentID = item => item.id !== id;

  const removeItem = (id, setList, list) => setList({...list, list: list.filter(item => isDifferentID(item))});

  return (
    <>
      {list.map(({text, id, setList, list}) => (
         <div onClick={() => removeItem(id, setList, list)}>{text}</div>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}
```

**Final notes:**

Functional style `discourages` functions with side effects that modify internal state or make other changes that aren't visible in the functions return value. We aiming for `statelessness and immutability` as much as possible.

**[Update]**

Thanks. I like your suggestion about the arguments I can see this add predictability to the function, so I updated it to include: `id, setList, list`

Comment: So for clarity sake, not all functions can be pure (obviously) and from Clean Code pg 45 "Functions should either do something or answer something, but not both. Either your
function should change the state... or it should return some information..."   Slightly paraphrased as it refers to OO Java example.  In this case the function is changing state and thus cannot be pure.  However I see the functional principals of immutability applied to your answer.

Comment: If we aim at statelessness and immutability would it be more correct to write `removeItem` like this?

`const removeItem = (id, setList, list) => setList({...list, list: list.filter(item => isDifferentID(item))});`

So that `removeItem` is only using it's input parameters rather than referencing the lexical scope.

Comment: Does calling `setList` with an object (in the `removeItem` function) matter when you first called it with an array at the start? Also, is spreading the current list into the object for `setList` redundant? To make it more `FP` the `removeItem` function could be partially applied with `list` and `setList` then supplied to your `onClick` property.

`const removeItem = (list, setList) => id => setList(list.filter(item => item.id !== id))`

Comment: Yeah, you are correct about the `setList` function detail, though I wasn't 100% concerned about that aspect @SuperJumbo more about what was passed in.  But obviously it's useful for future peeps.  Ok so we can say that functional React draws more boilerplate, for a function which is hidden in the function component and can't be tested directly.  Of course it could be abstracted out into an external module.  But this seems a little awkward for light weight components with one inner function.

Comment: @LeoLanese will you add the alternative HoF as an option?

Answer (score 0):

As per @SuperJumbo comment, I thought the solution detailed was an equally valid answer (using a higher order function).

```
const Component = ({data, onChange}) => {

  const [list, setList] = useState(data);

  const isDifferentID = item => item.id !== id;

  const removeItem = (list, setList) => id => setList(list.filter(item => item.id !== id))
  
  const removeListItem = removeItem(list, setList);

  return (
    <>
      {list.map(({text, id, setList, list}) => (
         <div onClick={() => removeListItem(id)}>{text}</div>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}
```

But to some degree both seem like additional boilerplate - perhaps unneeded when we look at the original question.